# Trying to use the docx.py project written by olebole and having no luck

Tags: python, python-2.7, ms-word

I am trying to use https://github.com/olebole/python-docx/blob/master/docx.py to do some formatting like italic and underline from what I understand it is a extension of the https://github.com/mikemaccana/python-docx project. I have python-docx project installed using pip but I am not sure how to install the https://github.com/olebole/python-docx/blob/master/docx.py project so I just overwrote the docx.py file in my python site-packages folder.  But that seems to give me a lot of issues when I write a simple code like this: 
    d = docx.open('example.docx',mode = 'create')
    d += docx.Text('This is just some test that needs to be italic.',italic = True)
    docx.writeto('Dokument.docx')
    docx.close()

I could find just one example on here https://github.com/olebole/python-docx/issues/1 that I am trying to follow.

If someone can point me in the correct direction on this it would really help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me, this project's code looks unmaintained.  I would strongly recommend you to look for other projects that let you accomplish your task.

For instance https://github.com/mikemaccana/python-docx lets you do [this](https://github.com/mikemaccana/python-docx/blob/master/example-makedocument.py).

```
body.append(paragraph([('This is italic text', 'i')]))
```

Comment: I agree with you but I really have not been able to find anything else .

Comment: `mikemaccana/python-docx` seems to be much more complete and better maintained/tested. Look at https://github.com/mikemaccana/python-docx/blob/a7130f3b1ad215207842d861f3333c0a2d3be7a4/docx.py#L157 for examples on how to add italicized/bold/underlined text.

Comment: Yeah that is part I don't get, I should be able to just add this body.append(docx.paragraph(paragraph_one,'iu')) to get italic text but it runs fine but it will not print italic text.

Comment: No, the code only lets you either add a string or a list of tuples. This works: `body.append(paragraph([('This is italic and underlined', 'ui')]))`

Comment: Do you have any idea how I can insert the degree symbol into this word  document?

Comment: Something like this should work: `body.append(paragraph(u'The temperature 25\xb0C'))`